# Как удалить отправленный альбом в aiogram 3.4.1

Tags: python, aiogram, асинхронность

Есть код, который показывает карточку товара после выбора категории. Главное меню удаляется и выходит карточка товара. Карточка представляет из себя: 3 изображения, текст с описанием товара и 3 Inline-кнопки(в корзину, следующий товар, главное меню). ". При нажатии на кнопку "главное меню" мне нужно удалить отправленный альбом из 3-х фотографий, сообщение с описанием и соответственно отправить меню. Проблема в том, что я не могу удалить этот альбом. Для описания использую delete(), для альбома пробовал message_delete(), но как бы я не пробовал я получаю ошибку. Как мне это сделать? Часть кода прикладываю:

```
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

import app.keyboards as kb
import app.parser.parser_module as Parser

from app.database.requests import (set_user)

router = Router()

@router.message(CommandStart())
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'to_main')
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    if isinstance(message, Message):
        await set_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username)
        await message.answer('Welcome!', reply_markup=kb.main)
    else:
        await message.message.delete()
        await message.message.answer('Main menu', reply_markup=kb.main)

@router.callback_query(F.data.startswith('category_'))
async def category(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await Parser.parser(str(callback.data.split('_')[0]), int(callback.data.split('_')[1]))

    msg = f'<b>{name}</b>\n\nЦена: {price}\n\nДоступные размеры: {sizes}'

    await callback.message.delete() 
    await callback.message.answer_media_group(media=photos)
    await callback.message.answer(msg, reply_markup=kb.to_main, parse_mode='html')
```